# Terminology with zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity $1$.

If for some $a \in R$ there exists $b \in R$ such that $ab = 1$, then we say that $a$ is a **unit** and that $b$ is a **multiplicative inverse** or **reciprocal** of $a$.

If for some $c \in R$ there exists nonzero $d \in R$ such that $cd = 0$, then we say that $c$ is a **zero divisor** and that $d$ is a `????????` of $c$.

> Is there a standard word to go in place of `????????`?

To clarify, I want a word that like "reciprocal of $a$", describes the relationship between $c$ and $d$.  "Zero divisor" itself doesn't cover this; if I just say $x,y$ are zero divisors, it doesn't imply that $xy = 0$.

Comment: I would just say $c$ and $d$ are both zero divisors.

Comment: If $R$ is commutative then $cd=0$ and $dc=0$ are equivalent. More generally in not necessarily commutative monoids we have notions of left/right inverse, unit, and zero divisor (in particular a unital ring under multiplication is a monoid with a zero).

Comment: @JohnHabert: It's the *relationship* between $c$ and $d$ that I want a word for.  If $x$ and $y$ are two arbitrary zero divisors then we may not have $xy=0$.

Comment: @seaturtles: Indeed, I chose a commutative ring to avoid the extra verbiage.

Comment: Sadly, I think the answer to your question is "No, there is no standard term for this relationship."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have an answer to my own question.  The set $\mathrm{Ann}(c) := \{d \in R : cd = 0\}$ is known as **the annihilator** of $c$ (it is actually an ideal of $R$).  So it might not be too great an abuse of terminology to also say that each element $d \in \mathrm{Ann}(c)$ is **an annihilator** of $c$.

Comment: Or more simply, $d$ annihilates $c$.

Comment: @hurkyl: Indeed, but I wanted a noun.

Answer (score 0):

If $c=0$, then we get noting interesting, e.g. $d$ is any nonzero element in our ring.  If $c\ne0$, then $d$ would also be a zero divisor, since $\exists{c}\in R$, with $c\ne0$ such that $cd=0$.

I am not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: I tried to clarify my question.

Comment: If this was unique, there might be a term for it, but consider $ab=0,a\ne0$ and $b\ne0$.  We know there exist other such zero divisors for $a$ and $b$.  For example, let $c\ne0$ be an element, such that $bc\ne0$ and $bc\ne b$.  This new element is clearly a zero divisor of $a$ since $abc=(ab)c=0c=0$.  In essence, every zero divisor has a set that when multiplied with it gives you zero.  You could call these zero divisors of $a$.

Comment: Thanks, that jogged my memory and reminded me of the word **annihilator**.